# How to access count and index of WKitInterface array?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I'm porting some code from an older ViewController to WKInterfaceController and am having difficulty accessing count and index for the beatPatternsArray. For now I simply want the custom function to index through the 4 different heart rates witch in turn display a different heart image. Am I doing everything right so far?

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


struct BeatPattern {
var heartImage = WKInterfaceImage()
var description = "Normal"
var bpm = 80

var duration: Double {
    return 60.0 / Double(bpm)
}
}

let redHeartFast = WKInterfaceImage()
let yellowHeartElevated = WKInterfaceImage()
let greenHeartNormal = WKInterfaceImage()
let purpleHeartSlow = WKInterfaceImage()
let blueHeartSedated = WKInterfaceImage()



class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

@IBOutlet weak var heartSymbol: WKInterfaceImage!

// @IBOutlet weak var bpmLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

var currentBeatPattern = BeatPattern()
var currentBeatPatternIndex = 0

var beatPatternsArray = [
    BeatPattern(heartImage: redHeartFast, description: "Fast", bpm: 180),
    BeatPattern(heartImage: yellowHeartElevated, description: "Elevated", bpm: 140),
    BeatPattern(heartImage: greenHeartNormal, description: "Normal", bpm: 80),
    BeatPattern(heartImage: purpleHeartSlow, description: "Slow", bpm: 55),
    BeatPattern(heartImage: blueHeartSedated, description: "Sedated", bpm: 30)]




override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    self.view.insertSubview(heartSymbol, atIndex: 1)   // Error

}

override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()

    // iconLabel.frame = self.view.bounds  // fix this, frame math definitely wont work.
    //iconLabel.f

    //iconLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    //iconLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(132)
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()

    newBeat()

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(8,
        target: self,
        selector: Selector("newBeat"),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)

    //beat()

}



func newBeat() {

    if ++currentBeatPatternIndex == beatPatternsArray.count {
        currentBeatPatternIndex = 0
    }

    currentBeatPattern = beatPatternsArray[currentBeatPatternIndex]

    //bpmLabel.setText("\(currentBeatPattern.bpm)")

    heartSymbol = currentBeatPattern.heartImage
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `beatPatternsArray` as a `WKInterfaceImage` but it appears to be an array of `BeatPattern`s.

You *could* declare it as `[BeatPattern]` instead of `WKInterfaceImage`, but from your initialization Swift can infer the type. So just use:

```
var beatPatternsArray = [
    BeatPattern(heartImage: yellowHeartFast, description: "Fast", bpm: 180),
    BeatPattern(heartImage: redHeartNormal, description: "Normal", bpm: 80),
    BeatPattern(heartImage: purpleHeartSlow, description: "Slow", bpm: 55),
    BeatPattern(heartImage: blueHeartSedated, description: "Fast", bpm: 30)]
```

(without the `: WKInterfaceImage`).

Then you will be able to use the array methods:

```
let beatCount = beatPatternsArray.count
let beatCountWithCountFunction = count(beatPatternsArray)
let secondElement = beatPatternsArray[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Ok but now of course Xcode is saying "use of unresolved identifier" for the 4 elements. But of course I can ignore that error for now until they are used right? Next, you gave me those 3 constant variables but how do I implement them? Do I paste them inside of the newBeat() function then pass them the way I already have passed them? Or do my passing methods have to be changed as well? i.e. `if ++currentBeatPatternIndex == beatPatternsArray.count {
            currentBeatPatternIndex = 0
        }
`

Comment: You should not ignore "use of unresolved identifier", or any error. In this case I'm guessing you made a typo. The 3 constants I provided were just examples of how you can access information from an array; you don't need to use them.

Comment: I just mean temporarily until I use the variables. Sometimes errors go away after they're used. I checked for typos but can't see any. Here are the errors. http://i.imgur.com/Oe0EFJO.png  Also, I'm still getting 2 errors in the newBeat() function. http://i.imgur.com/Aa7vbs4.png CodeSense doesn't have an auto-complete for the code I have in those 2 lines.

Comment: The first error is because you haven't declared `yellowHeartFast`, etc. You should declare them. I think that will also resolve your second error.

Comment: You're asking totally new questions now. Please post a new question for those.

Comment: Done! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724749/watchkit-willactivate-function-xcode-doesnt-like-self-view-insertsubview.   Btw, irrelevant comments deleted for brevity. Thanks again.