# WatchKit willActivate() function. Xcode doesn't like self.view.insertSubview

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have zero errors. Only problem is nothing displays in my simulator. I'm guessing it's because I don't have anything in awakeWithContext? I did have `self.view.insertSubview(heartSymbol, atIndex: 1)` but had an Xcode error. 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/px82s.png "InterfaceController doesn't have a member named 'view'". I also tried `self.heartSymbol = currentBeatPattern.heartImage` in the awakeWithContext() function but still no luck. Also I do not have a willActivate() function right now so is that ok for now?

In the beginning stages of coding this app I simply want to cycle through the 5 heartImages in the if loop in the newBeat() function then display them in the heartSymbol IBOutlet.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


struct BeatPattern {
var heartImage = WKInterfaceImage()
var description = "Normal"
var bpm = 80

var duration: Double {
    return 60.0 / Double(bpm)
}
}


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

@IBOutlet weak var heartSymbol: WKInterfaceImage!

var currentBeatPattern = BeatPattern()
var currentBeatPatternIndex = 0

var beatPatternsArray = [
    BeatPattern(heartImage: redHeartFast, description: "Fast", bpm: 180),
    BeatPattern(heartImage: yellowHeartElevated, description: "Elevated", bpm: 140),
    BeatPattern(heartImage: greenHeartNormal, description: "Normal", bpm: 80)]




override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    self.view.insertSubview(heartSymbol, atIndex: 1)   // Error

}

override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()

}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()

    newBeat()

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(8,
        target: self,
        selector: Selector("newBeat"),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)

    //beat()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WKInterfaceController is not directly related to a UIInterfaceController. It has no view property. WatchKit has no UIViews at all - it has WKInterfaceElements, but there is no way to dynamically insert them at runtime. All of your interface elements must be set up in Xcode's Interface Builder pane, although you can hide and show views at runtime and change a few settings, like strings or images.

Comment: The UIViewController is for the phone app, not the watch app. If you want something to appear on the watch, put the element in Interface.storyboard and the controlling code, if any, in InterfaceController.swift.

Comment: You don't have to have anything in ViewController, although if the user launches your app on the phone they'll expect to see something, even if only an instruction screen. You cannot add views on the watch at runtime. That is, all of your calls to WKInterfaceImage() are wrong and won't work. Create a WKInterfaceImage in your storyboard and you can change the image by setting the image property.

Comment: ok when you say calls to WKInterfaceImage are you talking about ONLY the method calls or also the declaration of any WKInterfaceImage variables and constants as well? Btw, I created only 1 WKInterfaceImage on the Interface.storyboard because my idea was to set that single WKInterfaceImage from the array of images. In my code I have `struct BeatPattern {
    var heartImage =  WKInterfaceImage ` . Should that be a UIImage?

Comment: I actually had some images in watch app NOT watch extension so they weren't loading lol Ridiculous. This new watch stuff got me all twisted ;) Anyway right now I have `self.heartSymbol.setImage(UIImage(named:"greenHeartNormal"))` and that loads a single image from assets fine but, what I really want is what you see in my array and newBeat() function. That if condition is supposed to cycle through the images and put them in the WKInterfaceImage IBOutlet but it's not. In newBeat() function I have `heartSymbol = currentBeatPattern.heartImage` but no luck.  What's the proper method?

Comment: I'm going to make this a new question. Redundant code and posts pruned.